# I get an integrity error when deleting a user in django admin

Tags: django

So I am creating a social medial app with Django and I have made a lot of model connections with users and profiles and now I am confused. When Ii try to delete a user, I get an error.

```
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I am not so sure but I think the error has to do with something about the `following`in the `model below. I tried creating a new user that is not following anyone and tried deleting it too, it worked! But the ones already follwing each other won't get deleted and raise the error above

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # creating a one to oe rel with a user model
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follows', symmetrical=False)
    joined_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to='post_images')
```

Comment: try one thing... put blank=True in following field. Might work

Comment: it did not work, @coderDude